# How to show that there are 4704 ways to choose 5 cards with exactly 3 Ace's from a deck of 52 cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm not actually sure if 4704 is the correct number of combinations. If my reasoning (in the next paragraph is correct), I need help showing why it makes sense.

*Scenario:*
Draw 5 cards from a regular deck of 52 cards. How many ways can we draw 5 cards that contains exactly 3 Ace's? No replacement.

*Reasoning:*
There are $4 \choose 3$ = 4 ways to select 3 cards (Aces). Since we're interested in counting the cases where there are 3 aces, we can assume that 3 of 5 cards we draw are aces. Since we drew 3 cards, there are 49 left from which we must select 2. There are $49 \choose 2$ = 1176 ways to select 2 cards.

Let A be the event in which we select 3 cards from which there are 4 possibilities. Let event B be the event in which we select 2 cards from which there are 1176 possibilities. We use the multiplication rule to find the total number of possibilities.

Comment: There are ${48 \choose 2}$ ways of choosing two non-Aces

Comment: Your title says 4704, the body says 4324

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: And the actual answer is more or less the average of those two.

Comment: Fixed. I don't remember if it was a typo or if 4324 was the incorrect solution I'd come up with at the time.

Comment: 4324 (which was previously in the body of the question) is $4 \times {47 \choose 2}$.  4704 (as in the title) is $4 \times {49 \choose 2}$.  The correct answer is $4 \times {48 \choose 2} = 4512$, "more or less the average".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error in your reasoning is that you are considering 49C2 as the number of ways of selecting the other 2 cards. It should actually be 48C2, because you can only have exactly 3 aces. The former case will also take into account those combinations which have 4 aces.

Comment: Understood! "Since we drew 3 cards, there are 49 left from which we must select 2" is incorrect. The 49 cards include the Ace that wasn't chosen *but* we must only count hands of 2 cards that *don't* include the Ace.

Answer (score 5):

You have to consider 48 cards not 49, since you want 3 aces (if you consider 49 cards you also count the hands with 4 aces).

Answer (score 5):

Multiply the number of ways to choose $3$ out of $4$ aces,

by the number of ways to choose $5-3$ out of $52-4$ non-aces:

$$\binom{4}{3}\cdot\binom{52-4}{5-3}=4512$$